# Mindstorm 2.0 & Chromebook?

Tags: mindstorms, nxt, software

We have a Mindstorms 2 (not the new one, last gen) and chromebooks... can we use the current software (EV3?) on our old Mindstorm brick?  If not, will the old software run on our chromebooks to program the old boy or will I have to use the old software which is still on my macbook?

Answer (score 2):

There's an FAQ that answers questions regarding the NXT <-> EV3 compatibility quite well:

https://www.lego.com/en-us/mindstorms/support?ignorereferer=true

The main problem is, that the EV3 software won't run on a chromebook AFAIK. Only Windows and Mac OS are supported. If you have a MacBook you can use the new EV3 software on that one and program the NXT.

Comment: It turns out that there is indeed a version of the EV3 education software that runs on a chromebook: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lego-mindstorms-education/jhnhfnolmcleankdkhfklakpchnccipg?hl=en-US

Comment: Oh wow. Thanks for the info! Looks like the version for iOS. That's awesome to know.